# jQuery setInterval preventing async ajax calls

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

A user fills out a form and clicks submit which then calls the utilsSubmit function.  The function sets some variables and then calls another function that begins reading a file.  If the file doesnt exist, it simply outputs "Connecting to device...".  Once the file exists it should put the output into a div.

While thats looping, I run another script via ajax that writes a file (the same file the readFile script is looking for.)

The problem is, the readFile function does not get called until the ajax call in utilsSubmit completes.  If I remove the setInterval "wrapper" and just run the readFile function it will work, however, I need it to keep looking for that file until I tell it to stop (deadman or certain string in the file.)

I need the readFile function to immediately trigger and output data to the browser.

```
function utilsSubmit(x){
    var stuff = x;
    file = "/path/to/file";
    deadman = 1;

    myTimer = setInterval(function() {
        readFile(file);
    }, 300);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "write_file.php",
      data: {
        "file": file
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#networkUtils").html(data);
      }
    });
};

function readFile(x) {
    var file = x;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "read_file.php",
      data: {
        "file": file
      },
    success: function(data) {
        $("#networkUtils").html(data);
        if (data.indexOf("END OF FILE")) {
            clearInterval(myTimer);
        }
     }
    });
    if (deadman >= 1000) {
        clearInterval(myTimer);
    }
    deadman++;
}
```

**EDIT - Tried setTimout as suggested**
The issue now, however, is I'm unable to exit out of the loop.  If I try to set the setTimeout result to a var, then clearTimeout on that var based on some logic, the function only runs the first time (it does not loop.)

Updated code:

```
function utilsSubmit(x){
    var name = x;
    file = "/path/to/file";
    deadman = 1;

    var myTimer;
    readFile(file);

    // AJAX Call to Write to file...
};

function readFile(x) {
    var file = x;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "read_file.php",
      data: {
        "file": file
      },
    success: function(data) {
        $("#networkUtils").html(data);
        if (data.indexOf("END OF FILE")) {
            clearInterval(myTimer);
        }
     }
    });
    if (deadman >= 1000) {
        clearInterval(myTimer);
    }
    deadman++;
    myTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        readFile(file);
    }, 300)
}
```

Comment: What if you simply call the function and then use `setTimeout` inside it to call itself again?

Comment: Good point.  I actually did some more reading after I posted this and determined the `setTimeout` route is probably a better method.  Trying that now.

Comment: Tried `setTimeout`.  It works, but I'm having issues exiting.  Updated issue description with code etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the issue lies here:

```
if (data.indexOf("END OF FILE")) {
    clearInterval(myTimer);
}
```

`indexOf` returns `-1` if the string is not found.  `-1` is "truthy".  The only time the `clearInterval` would not run is if `indexOf` returned `0`, meaning the "END OF FILE" was the very first character.  I assume you want to quit when it finds `"END OF FILE" anywhere, in which case it should be this:

```
if (data.indexOf("END OF FILE") != -1) {
    clearInterval(myTimer);
}
```

Comment: That was it!!  Thanks James!